# Usar @media, @media screen and ou @media only screen and Tem alguma diferença?

Tags: css, css3

Queria saber se tem alguma diferença no css ao usar um desses media queries,

Exemplo A:

```
@media(max-width:770px) {
    .texto{
        color:red
    }
}
```

Exemplo B:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 770px) {
    .texto{
        color:red;
    }
}
```

Exemplo C:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 770px) {
    body {
        color:red;
    }
}
```

Fiz testes aqui com cada um deles, e todos funcionaram.

Tem diferença?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Sim existem diferença, até pq nem toda a `@media` é `screen`, pode ser `print` por exemplo

```
@media(max-width:770px) {
    .texto{
        color:red
    }
}
```

No exemplo acima significa que para qualquer mídia que a largura seja de até 770px, mesmo seja uma TV, Monitor e até uma Impressora, a regra CSS ali contida vai ser aplicada.

Já nesse exemplo abaixo significa que em mídias do tipo `screen` **e** com telas de até 770px de largura a regra vai ser aplicada. (esse **e** é muito importante, pois o CSS só é aplicado se as **duas** regras `screen` e `max-width` corresponderem)

```
@media screen and (max-width: 770px) {
    .texto{
        color:red;
    }
}
```

**Sobre o `and`**

Veja que a sua regra @media pode ser bem complexa, e vc pode encadear vários parâmetros que deve ser atendidos para a regra ser aplicada. Por exemplo:

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    body { line-height: 1.4; }
}
```

Repare que vc vai "somando" requisitos com o `and`, logo para esse css ser aplicado precisa que:

```
a mídia tem que ser tela 
**e** ter no mínimo 320px de largura 
**e** no máximo 480px de largura
**e** a tela deve ter densidade de pixel de 2
```

**Se um dos requisitos não retornar `true` a regra não é aplicada**

> The `and` operator **is used for combining multiple media features together** into a single media query, requiring each chained feature to return `true` in order for the query to be `true`. It is also used for joining media features with media types.

---

Nesse outro exemplo o seletor `only` significa que apenas para mídia `screen` e com telas até 600px a regra vai ser aplicada. ***Essa regra não será aplicada a outras mídias como a `print` por exemplo***

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    body {
        color:red;
    }
}
```

## Exemplo de uso

Vamos supor que vc tenha um elemento na cor Amarela, que aparece bem na Tela do Computador, mas quando for imprimir o Amarelo não vai ficar legal e vc gostaria que ele ficasse Preto, como vc poderia resolver isso? Simples, usando `@media only print`. Então no seu CSS vc teria algo como:

```css
div {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

@media only print {
    div {
        background-color: black;
    }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Repare que com o exemplo acima quando vc der um <kbd>Ctrl+P</kbd> a `div` não vai aparecer Amarela, vai ficar Preta!

**Sobre o `Only`**

> The `only` operator is used to apply a style only if an entire query matches, and is useful for preventing older browsers from applying selected styles. If you use the `only` operator, you must **specify an explicit media type**.

Em português
*O operador `only` é usado para aplicar um estilo somente se uma consulta inteira corresponder e é útil para impedir que navegadores mais antigos apliquem estilos selecionados. Se você usar o operador `only`, **deverá especificar um tipo de mídia explícito.*** (no caso se o tipo de mídia é `screen`, `print` ou `speech`)

**Um esclarecimento sobre o Only**

> The keyword ‘only’ can also be used to hide style sheets from older user agents. User agents must process media queries starting with ‘only’ as if the ‘only’ keyword was not present.

Ao que parece o atributo `only` também pode ser usado para que navegadores antigos ignorem a regra de css contida no `@media`, uma vez que eles podem não fazer distinção entre os tipos de mídia diferentes, veja que eles podem não ver diferença entre um `@media screen` de um `@media print`, para esses navegadores tudo seria uma coisa só. Então para fazer com que eles ignorem a regra se usa o `only`.

***Resumindo***: Nos navegadores que entendem a diferença entre `print` e `screen` não há necessidade do `only`, porém, nos navegador que não entendem as diferenças entre as mídias se usa o `only` para que ele não reconheça a tag e a ignore.

Fonte1: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/@media 
Fonte2: https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Comment: Obrigado Hugo, mas tenho uma duvida, o que você quer dizer com mídias do tipo screen? poderia me explicar?

Comment: Consegue dar um exemplo de quando a condição `screen and (max-width: 770px)` é válida que `only screen and (max-width: 770px)` não é (para demonstrar a diferença que o `only` faz)?

Comment: @RenanOsorio existem mídias impressas,e mídias de tela. Por exemplo, vc pode ter uma cor amarela pro texto na tela, mas quer que na impressão ele fique preto, ai vc usa `@media only print` e coloca a cor preta para o texto ficar mais legível depois de impresso.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss dei o exemplo no comment, mas vou incluir na resposta com mais detalhes, valeu o toque

Comment: @hugocsl Obrigado!

Comment: @hugocsl Mas neste caso apenas `print` ao invés de `only print` não basta? https://output.jsbin.com/lotecixemi

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss acho que entendi o que vc quis dizer, que o only print seria redundante já que só com o print a regra já se aplicaria apenas no print mesmo e não no screen confere?

Comment: @hugocsl Exatamente. Não consegui visualizar uma situação em que o `only` realmente seria necessário.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss aparentemente algus navegadores, acredito que os mais antigos, não fazem distinção entre os tipos de mídia, então usando o only na frente da regra os navegadores que não entenderem esse valor vão ignorar a regra. Repare no "also"... The keyword ‘only’ can also be used to hide style sheets from older user agents. User agents must process media queries starting with ‘only’ as if the ‘only’ keyword was not present.

Comment: @hugocsl parabéns pela explicação, super didático e respondeu tudo que eu precisava. Obrigado

Comment: @RenanOsorio eu achei que conseguiria responder com poucas linhas :D, mas depois que foi atentando aos detalhes achei que poderia ser uma resposta mais completa rss

Answer (score 0):

A grande diferença tem a ver com as resoluções que queres o 1 linha de código e para aquela resolução(assume a resolucao e ajusta a outros ecrans) a 2 linha e para screen e a resolução(consegue ler em outras ecran ajustando) e a 3 linha de código e só para ecran e aquela resolução(só lê em ecrans e aquela formatação especifica) mas le o link explica melhor que eu ( quando digo screen são monitores tipo pc )
[info da google dev](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ux/responsive/)