# Problema com media queries do CSS

Tags: html, css3, layout-responsivo, media-queries

Estou tentando fazer minha aplicação rodar em *smartphones*, além do padrão desktop. Mas não consigo fazer as media queries  funcionarem de forma correta.

Só está funcionando até o tamanho da tela de tablet. Quando minimizo a tela para o tamanho do *smartphone* não funciona.

**Meu código:**

```css
/*dataTable*/

td.highlight {
    background-color: whitesmoke !important;
}
/*Responsivo nos seguintes dispositivos: google chrome, tablets (paisagem e retrato), smartphone*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 1920px), (max-width: 1080px), (max-width: 100em){
    body {
        background-color: #b3b3e6;
    }
    /* ========================= PAGINA DE GERAR DSS ================================== */
    #form_excel {
        padding: 10px;
    }
    #title_scroll_box {
        display: block;
    }
    .container {
        scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
        /*faz com que os elementos fiquem dentro do scroll, independente se a lista
                              adiciona ou remove elementos. Os elementos carregados e mostrados a medida
                              que a barra de rolagem desce  */
    }
    .nabvar {
        background-color: #000080;
        color: white;
        margin-bottom: 1.5em;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 20pt;
    }
    @font-face {
        font-family: Drops;
        src: url('../fonts/Drops.ttf');
    }
    .title_gerador_dss {
        font-family: Drops;
        font-size: 30pt;
    }
    #excel_file {
        width: 40em;
        padding: 2em;
        border-radius: 13px;
        background-color: white;
        margin-bottom: 5em;
        padding-bottom: 4em;
    }
    .data_form {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    #options {
        margin-bottom: 30em;
        color: black;
        background-color: black;
    }
    #gerar_dss {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-top: 3em;
        margin-left: 15em;
        margin-right: 1em;
    }
    .btn_bold {
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    #loading_icon {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    /* ============================= PAGINA DE HISTORICO ========================= */
    #historico {
        width: 40em;
        height: 9em;
        padding: 2em;
        border-radius: 13px;
        background-color: white;
        margin-bottom: 5em;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #historico-table {
        border-style: hidden;
    }
    caption {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 20pt;
        font-family: serif;
    }
    .margin_btn_history {
        margin-right: 0.5em;
    }
    /* ======================== MENSAGENS DE ERRO E SUCESSO ================================ */
    #msg_error {
        font-family: monospace;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 15pt;
    }
    #process-success {
        height: 6em;
        font-family: monospace;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 15pt;
        height: 3.3em;
        background-color: #32CD32;
    }
    .material-icons {
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .bold {
        color: black;
        font-size: 16pt;
        font-family: fantasy;
    }
    .toast-success {
        background: green;
    }
    .toast-error {
        background: red;
    }
    .div-scroll {
        overflow: scroll;
        height: 380px;
        width: 380px;
        position: relative;
    }
    .message {
        width: 100%;
        border: 1px solid;
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 13pt;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
    .message-error {
        border-color: #d32f2f;
        background-color: #ef5350;
        color: white;
    }
    .message-success {
        border-color: #32CD32;
        background-color: #00FF00;
        color: white;
    }
    #messages-form {
        display: none;
    }
    #process-error {
        display: none;
    }
    #process-success {
        display: none;
    }
    #process-loading {
        display: none;
    }
    .center {
        text-align: center;
    }
    /*Regra para a animacao*/
    @keyframes spin {
        0% {
            transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        100% {
            transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
    }
    /*Classe que mostra a animacao 'spin'*/
    .loader {
        border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
        animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #aplicacao {
        max-width: 10em;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <title>Alerta DSS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/style.css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<body>
<!-- GERARDOR DE ARQUIVO EXCEL (DADOS DE DSS) -->
    <div id="aplicacao" class="container">
        <div class="container" id="excel_file">
            <!--MENSAGENS DE ERRO DO FORMULÁRIO-->
            <div class="message message-error" id="messages-form">
                <a class="right" href="#"><i id="close-message-form" class="material-icons">close</i></a>
                <ul class="list-error" id="error-msg"></ul>
            </div>
            <!--MENSAGEM DE SUCESSO DA GERAÇÃO DE DSS-->
            <div class="message message-error" id="process-error">
                <a class="right" href="#"><i id="close-message-error" class="material-icons">close</i></a>
                <span><h5>Não foi possível gerar o arquivo DSS.</h5></span>
            </div>
            <!--MENSAGENS DE ERRO DA GERAÇÃO DE DSS-->
            <div class="message message-success " id="process-success">
                <a class="right" href="#"><i id="close-message-success" class="material-icons">close</i></a>
                <span><h5>DSS gerado com sucesso.</h5></span>
            </div>
            <form id="form_excel">

                <!-- FORMULARIO PARA ESPECIFICAR OS DADOS QUE DEVERA CONSTAR NO ARQUIVO EXCEL GERADO -->

                <p>
                    <label class="bold" for="inicio">Data Inicial </label>
                    <input type="date" id="inicio" required>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label class="bold" for="fim">Data Final </label>
                    <input type="date" id="fim" required>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label class="bold" for="nome_arquivo">Nome para o Arquivo (Sem a extensão .dss): </label>
                    <input type="text" id="nome_arquivo" required placeholder="Será o nome do arquivo .dss a ser gerado">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label class="bold" for="observacao">Observação </label> - Opcional
                    <input type="text" id="observacao" placeholder="Será o nome do arquivo .dss a ser gerado">
                </p>

                <p> <label class="bold data_form" for="tipo">Tipo de Dado </label>
                    <select id="tipo" required>
                                <option value="" disabled selected>Escolha um tipo</option>
                                <option value="HORARIO">HORÁRIO</option>
                                <option value="DIARIO">DIÁRIO</option>
                                <option value="MEDIAS_PCD">MÉDIAS PCD</option>
                                <option value="CHUVA_ACUMULADA">CHUVA ACUMULADA</option>
                            </select>
                </p>

                <p id="title_tipos_dados"> <label class="bold">Selecione o(s) tipos de dados que deseja gerar:</label></p>

                <p>
                    <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="chuva" class="filled-in" value="dss_chuva"/>
                                <span>CHUVA</span>
                            </label>
                </p>

                <p>
                    <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="cota" class="filled-in" value="dss_cota"/>
                                <span>COTA</span>
                            </label>
                </p>

                <p>
                    <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="vazao" class="filled-in" value="dss_vazao"/>
                                <span>VAZÃO</span>
                            </label>
                </p>

            </form>

            <!-- LISTA SCROLL COM AS OPCOES DE ESTACAO -->
            <form>
                <p class="bold">Selecione a estação desejada:</p>
                <section class="container div-scroll">
                    <section id="estacoes_sace">
                    </section>
                    <section id="estacoes_hidro">
                    </section>
                </section>
                <div class="center" id="process-loading">
                    <br>
                    <div class="preloader-wrapper small active">
                        <div class="spinner-layer spinner-blue-only">
                            <div class="circle-clipper left">
                                <div class="circle"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="gap-patch">
                                <div class="circle"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="circle-clipper right">
                                <div class="circle"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a href="#" id="gerar_dss" class="btn btn_bold">Gerar Dados</a>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

O que estou fazendo errado?

Comment: Mas o que é que não estão funcionando?? Qual é o problema? Como está e como deveria ficar?

Comment: Editei a pergunta.

Comment: Sabe que `@media only screen and (max-width: 1920px), (max-width: 1080px), (max-width: 100em){` vai considerar apenas a maior medida, né?!

Comment: Não, pensei que consideraria todas as medidas que especifiquei. Então preciso separar as queries em blocos de código diferentes?

Comment: Então, acredito que você não tenha entendido o básico das media queries. Apesar de ser beem extenso, considere uma leitura: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/CSS_Media_queries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu `@media` está bem confuso, não sei se essa resposta vai resolver o problema totalmente, mas espero que te ajudo e entender como vc vai montar suas regras de `media querie`

Repare que isso

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1920px), (max-width: 1080px), (max-width: 100em) {}
```

Significa que é para aplicar o CSS se á tela for, `largura máxima de 1080px`, `largura máxima de 1920px`, `largura máxima de 100em` *(1 em normalmente é 16px, então 100em = 1600px)*. Logo a partir de `1080px` que é o menor tamanho ele já aplica o CSS, os outros tamanho são redundantes, pois eles já vai herdar os estilos de qualquer forma....

Outra coisa é que a menor media queri que é a `@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) { }` vc colocou por último... Isso é errado, o menor tamanho de `max-width` sempre deve vir primeiro, para não ser sobrescrito pelo `@media` que vier depois. Recomendo que leia essa resposta [Usar @media, @media screen and ou @media only screen and Tem alguma diferença?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/341742/usar-media-media-screen-and-ou-media-only-screen-and-tem-alguma-diferen%C3%A7a/341745#341745)

Não posso afirma, mas se vc estava pensando em `Mobile First` acredito que pela forma que vc fez talvez no lugar de `max-width` vc queria colocar `min-width`, mesmo assim o que falei da redundância fica valendo, ao "atingir" o primeiro valor o que vier depois é redundante e não faz sentido. Recomendo que leia essa outra resposta para te ajudar a entender o conceito de `@medias min-width` e `Mobile First` [Media Queries Não funciona Medidas Informadas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/351972/media-queries-n%C3%A3o-funciona-medidas-informadas/351977#351977)

Outra observação,

Repare que esse `@media`, veja que eu tenho dois valores com um `and` (max-width: 900px) and (min-width: 600px) e uma separação com uma `,` (min-width: 1100px)

```
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) and (min-width: 600px), (min-width: 1100px) { }
```

Significa que, quando a largura está **entre** `600px` e `900px` **OU** acima de `1100px` o CSS é aplicado. Então entre 0px e 600px e entre `900px` e `1100px` os estilos desse `@media` não sera aplicado. Na largura mínima de `1100px` o estilo é aplicado!

Answer (score 1):

> "*- Alguém saberia apontar o que estou fazendo errado?*"

Não vou analisar e/ou reproduzir seu código por completo. Minha resposta vai ser limitada a esta parte:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1920px), (max-width: 1080px), (max-width: 100em){
```

Primeiro ponto: `only screen` quer dizer que as regras serão aplicadas somente em telas. Ou seja: não serão aplicadas em uma impressão, por exemplo;

Segundo: `(max-width: 1920px), (max-width: 1080px), (max-width: 100em)`

Apesar do navegador interpretar "dessa forma", ele vai considerar todas essas regras. Mas veja por esse lado: não tem lógica limitar a `1920px` **OU** `1080px` **OU** `100em`. Na prática, prevalece a maior, já que todas se tratam do `max-width`.

Terceiro: toda a estilização da sua página só será aplicada "se forem atendidas as regras da media query". O ideal é você estilizar o padrão para TUDO e depois fazer a media query contendo **apenas o que muda para tal regra**.

---

Uma palhinha (exemplo) bem superficial sobre as *media queries* (redimensione sua tela para testar):

```css
div.exemplo {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
@media (min-width: 100px) and (max-width: 200px){
    div.exemplo {
        background-color: red;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 200px) and (max-width: 300px){
    div.exemplo {
        background-color: blue;
        width: 100px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 400px){
    div.exemplo {
        background-color: yellow;
        height: 100px;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 600px){
    /*
     * DEFINI APENAS O MÁXIMO
     * ESSA REGRA SERÁ APLICADA EM CONJUNTO ÀS DEMAIS
     * DESDE QUE O LIMITE MÁXIMO DA LARGURA DA
     * VIEWPORT SEJA 600px
     */
    div.exemplo {
        border: solid 3px green;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 350px){
    /*
     * DEFINI APENAS O MÍNIMO
     * ESSA REGRA SERÁ APLICADA EM CONJUNTO ÀS DEMAIS
     * DESDE QUE O LIMITE MÍNIMO DA LARGURA DA
     * VIEWPORT SEJA 350px
     *
     * REPARE QUE ELA ESTÁ "DEPOIS" DA REGRA DE 600PX
     * ISSO SIGNIFICA QUE ELA VAI SOBRESCREVÊ-LA
     */
    div.exemplo {
        border: dotted 3px blue;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta
            name="viewport"
            content=
                "width=device-width,
                user-scalable=yes,
                initial-scale=1.0,
                maximum-scale=10, minimum-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="exemplo"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```